# Is there a way to fix the height of PrimeNg DataTable irrespective of the number of rows?

Tags: primeng

Currently the default behavior of PrimeNG DataTable is that it adjusts its height according to the number of rows to display.
We can fix the scrollheight, but if the number of rows are less table again adjusts to a smaller height.

Comment: You'd like to have a min-height feature but it doesn't exist ? If yes, why wouldn't you fix a min-height to a div containing this datatable ?

Comment: @Antikhippe : Because in that case the actual table doesn't extend and hence the datatable scrollbar doesn't come at the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `min-height` to the body of this table. Try this:

```
::ng-deep .your-table .ui-datatable-scrollable-view .ui-datatable-scrollable-body {
    min-height: 27vh;
}
```

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. can you explain clearly

Comment: It means by default the table will be smaller if you have fewer rows, so this solution is to make the table have a fixed min-height. What is your problem? Why do you link to Primeng documentation?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `[tableStyle]="{'min-height': '30rem'}"`